# Como faço para saber se o usuário está atualizando a página

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

O usuário está enchendo o carrinho com vários itens, e eu criei uma função jQuery onde os itens são somados instantaneamente e apresentados a ele. Assim que ele termina de escolher os itens e clica no botão de prosseguir, os itens e o valor são salvos no banco de dados. Porém se ele atualizar a página apertando f5, ou clicando na imagem do browser para atualizar, os valores e os itens são zerados da tela.

Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que **não são zerados do banco**, eu gostaria de saber como identificar essa atualização, para poder trabalhar o ajax e poder também apagar os dados do banco.

Comment: Primeiro: por que você gostaria de apagar os dados se o usuário simplesmente atualizar a página? Segundo: existe o evento [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), mas ele é bem limitado, não dá pra fazer requisições assíncronas em seu handler.

Comment: A ideia seria guardar um `cookie`. Se a página está sendo atualizada, o `cookie` existe, caso contrário, não.

Comment: O Correto é só salvar no banco após ele atualizar na tela, pelo que entendi você salva assim que o usuário digita?

Comment: Starta uma sessão na página sempre que o usuário acessar, destrua e starte novamente sempre que a página é atualizada e salve ela junto no banco de dados, sempre que a página for atualizada  destrua a sessão e crie uma nova, não esqueça de capturar o valor da sessão que vai ser destruida para que você possa excluir todos os dados do banco que possuam ela.

Comment: Eu criaria um ajax para alimentar uma sessão em php em cada vez que um item for adicionado. Ao carregar a página (depois do f5), a sessão seria lida no campos predeterminados. Ou seja, você teria que trabalhar com calculos js e leitura e escrita de sessão.

Comment: Boa pessoal, desculpem a demora, muito trabalho por aqui, consegui resolver o meu problema, era apenas uma questão de lógica. É que na hora você só pensa em querer resolver, resolver e, acaba não descansando a mente. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Se você não quiser ficar gastando requisição para adicionar os itens coloque eles em uma sessão local e quando quiser salve no banco.

Answer (score 0):

vc pode usar uma função no onexit, e ao sair da página a função é chamada.
O que voce precisaria é saber qual o id da session que o usuário está, e antes de destruir a sessao, dar um delete da base, com base nos dados de session q estão se destruindo.